# Apache2 SSL: None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (works with www. but not without)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2, lets-encrypt

I'm using https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html to check my site, and it's failing with this error message:

`None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (example.net). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser. It looks like you just need to add the "www." when accessing the site with SSL. Learn more about name mismatch errors.`

My `000-default-le-ssl.conf` is set up like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName example.net
        ServerAlias www.example.net

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.net
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.net-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.net-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.net
  ServerAlias www.example.net
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.net/
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Is it because I only have `SSLCertificateFile`s for `www.example.net` and I'm missing one for `example.net`? I tried to force a redirect to `www.example.net` to work around this if so.

**(Update: Solved below)**

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** I tried to reinstall lets encrypt via `sudo certbot --apache` and then when asked `Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?` I chose both options `1. example.net 2. www.example.net` (I must have only chosen the `www` option in the past.)